# Non-convex optimization without using gradient descent

Tags: optimization, non-convex

If we want to optimize a convex function, we could use methods like gradient descent or computing the derivative of the function and equalize to zero so we can obtain the global minimum.

But I wonder if it's possible to compute the derivative of a non-convex function  to obtain all the local minima. Is this possible?

Are there methods other than gradient descents to optimize non-convex functions?

Comment: Could you be more precise? Imagine a noisy function (e.g. http://users.iems.northwestern.edu/~ama132/images/test1.svg ) , such function has hundreds of local minimas, to find them you'd need to do a grid search on a grid covering all the possible values... This wouldn't be an optimization problem.

Comment: So in that noisy function, isn't it possible to compute the derivative and obtain all the local minimas, and then evaluate with our function which one is the lower?

Comment: Finding where the gradient vanishes does not give you the global minimum, but rather (all) local minima (if they exist). Your question has erroneous statements. Moreover, "function" is extremely broad. Continuous? Differentiable? Smooth? Polynomial? Please narrow down.

Comment: Neither gradient descent gives you the global minimum, that's why I'm trying to understand why we prefer to use gradient descent, instead of computing the derivative. I am referring to function in the context of Machine Learning cost functions, which are normally continuous and differentiable.

Comment: You just introduced a new tag [non-convex], can you please add a tag wiki?

Comment: @csvreel I have edited my answer in response to your comment on why we prefer to use gradient descent instead of computing the derivative. Please have a look and let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: Finding where the gradient vanishes requires solving a system of equations, which is generally not easy. If the function happens to be quadratic, then the equations are linear and one can use linear algebra. You seem to assume that systems of equations are easy to solve.

Comment: Thanks Andreas and Rodrigo, both answers clarify me what I was not understanding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It really depends on the function. For some functions you can compute the derivative to obtain the local minima, e.g. $\sin x$ is non-convex but it is straightforward to find all its minima ($k\pi, k\in \mathbb{Z}$).

Gradient descent also works well on non-convex functions, but it will find a local minimum. There are techniques to "push" the gradient descent out of a local minimum hoping it will find a global minimum or a better local minimum.

For example, [stochastic gradient descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent) calculates the gradient based on only one sample at a time. This not only speeds up computation of the gradient(because we only use one sample), it can also help to avoid getting stuck in a local minimum. This happens because single samples tend to be noisy, and that noise can be enough to push towards a better solution.

There are also second-order methods like the [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method_in_optimization), which uses the second derivative to optimize the step direction.

Two other widely used methods are the [BFGS method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broyden%E2%80%93Fletcher%E2%80%93Goldfarb%E2%80%93Shanno_algorithm) and [conjugate gradient descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method).

This also depends on what exactly you are trying to achieve. If you are training a neural network, there are more specific techniques you can use. For example you can train multiple neural networks with different starting values. This will lead to different local minima during training and as a result you can take an ensemble of your different neural networks.

There are a ton of other methods you can use to optimize a non-convex function and it would be quite difficult(if at all possible) to include all of them in a post. There is also quite a lot of research being done in this area.

To answer your comment on why would you use gradient descent instead of just finding the local minima analytically, two main reasons come to mind: a) if an analytical solution exists, it might be computationally more difficult to compute than gradient descent. After you derive the formula for the gradient, you still need to set it to 0 and then solve it with respect to the parameters you are trying to optimize. That might involve calculating the inverse of some matrix. This is not necessarily true, if all you want is to calculate the gradient so that you can use it in gradient descent. b)It is possible that an analytical solution does not exist or it is too complicated. You can still approximate the gradient using numerical methods which you can then use in gradient descent.